# Make application compatible with both iPhone and iPad?

Tags: ios

I'm a junior iPhone programmer. I made a ball game application for the iPhone which I'm unable to run on the iPad. I have no idea how to run iPhone applications on iPad. So how do I make my application compatible with both iPhone and iPad?

Comment: Google "how to make iOS universal application" and you will find a dozens of tutorials about that.

Comment: What do you mean by "i am unable to run it on iPad"? Does it crash? Are you seeing error messages?

Answer (score 2):

select your project on the left side in xcode 4.3, select your first target, select the tab "Summary" and choose as device "Universal" instead of "iPhone", that app will run fullscreen on the ipad instead of a little iPhone window